# fail to clone repository from open shift server

Tags: git, windows-7, openshift

after installing red hot client tools and git (windows) i am trying to clone the repository created on the server for my application, but I am getting this error:

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.

I have verified that the fingerprints of keys stored locally and used on server for my application match (they do), would appreciate any help.

Edit: i did the exact same thing from the git console (not the normal windows command console, and not the git gui tool - no success with either of them), and it worked fine.

Comment: Are you cloning with the RHC tools or just straight git? If just straight git then please do 

git clone -vvv

Windows can have problems looking for the key in a different space than ssh expects it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to mark this as solved, details are in edited question.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

1. Delete all the files in the folder (C:\Users\user_acount\**.openshift**)
2. Open cmd prompt and type 'rhc setup'
3. Give server host name 'openshift.redhat.com'
4. Give login details
5. It will ask you whether to create a new security token. type 'Yes'
6. New security token will be uploaded successfully.

Now, you try to clone your git repository in local windows machine.

=> git clone git_url directory_to_create

Answer (score 1):

The thread is old, I know..

I had similar problems and doing the following on my local machine did it:

```
ssh-agent
ssh-add 'path to private key'
ssh-add -l
```

This let me do the initial `git clone ssh://...` for my openshift repository.